# Path of the main script

Tags: node.js

I'm making an app in NodeJS that's divided into many files in diffent directories.

Let's say that this is it's structure:

```
├── modules
│   └── something.js
├── config.json
└── main.js
```

I am running the `main.js` and it is using `something.js` for some tasks. How can I get the path of `main.js` in `something.js`, so I can include `config.json` in it?

When I tried to use `__dirname` in `something.js` it returned the path of `something.js`, not `main.js`.

Comment: ... Go up a directive from ` something`. But why? Either put the config where it's used, or load the config earlier.

Comment: `__dirname + '/../main.js'`?

Comment: you dont use full paths in nodejs, use relative path. If you are in `something.js` and want to include `main.js` just use `require('../main')`

Comment: I want my app to work in both Linux and Windows.